# AS2 TweenLite in For array not working?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, actionscript-2, gsap

I have a series of movieclips declared in an array.
In the array I have the name of the movieclip and the x, y position.
I am looping through the array but TweenLite doesn't seem to animate them.
The tweenLite onComplete does fire and the array data is good.

```
    for(var i=0; i < mcArray.length; i++){
        var mcName = mcArray[i][0];
        var mcX = mcArray[i][1];
        var mcY = mcArray[i][2];
        var delaytime = '0.'+i;
        trace(i+' | '+mcName+' = '+mcX+','+mcY+'  | '+delaytime);
        TweenMax.to(mcName,1, {delay:delaytime, _alpha:100,_x:mcX,_y:mcY, onCompleteParams:[mcName], onComplete:done}); 
    }
    function done(mcName){
        trace(mcName+' should be complete?');
    }
```

The array data is as follow:

```
    _level0.mc_one
     23.8
    47

    _level0.mc_two
    38.15
    48.7

    _level0.mc_three
    61.5
    47.25
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I solved it.
I now have two arrays, one with the movieclip names and one with the x,y positions.
All seems to work nice and well now.